# How to use vs code to debug python running with Cygwin64

Tags: python, cygwin, virtualenv, visual-studio-code

I need to run our python project on Ubuntu system, but I want to code it on my PC, others, some python library is not supported on Windows, so I download cygwin, use the installed python to run our project successfully.

Before use the cygwin, I have debug with local python successfully, But the problem is I can't use vs code to debug with the python in cygwin packet.

PS: I change the "python.pythonPath": "python" to  "python.pythonPath": "C:\cygwin64\bin\python2.7.exe" is not working.

PPS: I change the "launch.json" to be the blow, it will say "Source \cygdrive\f\project\python\security\app\models\f:\project\python\security\app\models\Capture.py is not available."

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Python",
        "type": "python",
        "request": "launch",
        "stopOnEntry": true,
        "program": "${file}",
        "pythonPath": "C:/cygwin64/bin/python2.7.exe",
        "debugOptions": [
            "WaitOnAbnormalExit",
            "WaitOnNormalExit",
            "RedirectOutput"
        ]
    }
```

For now, I don't know how to solve this problem, please help.

Comment: try "pythonPath": "/usr/bin/python2.7"

Comment: It's not working, says "spawn /usr/bin/python2.7.exe ENOENT"

Comment: Sorry, I missed the call was from not cygwin to python cygwin .How is ${file} ?

Comment: not work.  Error msg: "Error: spawn UNKNOWN"

Comment: I was asking what was the content and the format

Comment: @user1140109, unfortunately using VS Code with Cygwin isn't supported yet. An issue has been added for this. https://github.com/DonJayamanne/pythonVSCode/issues/194. Instead of using cygwin (as a temporary solution), you could place the files locally on windows and use the windows python executable.